# API-Platform: Entity with default WHERE clause

Tags: sql, orm, doctrine, where-clause, api-platform.com

I'm new to Symfony, Doctrine and the Api-Platform Bundle.

Is there a way to filter a collection by default.
I'm working with a SQL View which provides about 3.000 Rows. In my application I need only a few (about 500 or so).

By default, the generated entity show the whole view. In this view exists a column with a string value (showInList). Now i would like to have a way that the api-platform shows only all employees with this specific value. 
I know thats possible to set a filter. But if I remove the filter or override it I get all Employees.

It would be cool to do something like that

```
@ORM\Entity(where="visibility = 'showInList'"
```

Sorry for my poor english and thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an extension do that. Here is a working example: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions